# How to use show icons into expand widget like the block of github in flutter with

Tags: flutter, dart

There're two questions.

01.
I want to show more rows of icons with **one List only**. As you see from Fig3, I'm using three rows in Expand widget, in Card, and each row has the corresponding List. I think it was not so nice to build like this way.

02.
Which widget will be more suitable to build blocks view Github in Flutter?

Fig1.

[image]

Fig2.

[image]

Fig3.

[image]

```dart
    body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('TrahsCollection',
              style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 13),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _item.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  final String item = _item[index];
                  final MaterialColor = Colors.blue;
                  return Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
                      child: Card(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                        elevation: 10,
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Expanded(
                              flex:2,
                              child: ListTile(
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.amber[300],
                                  child: Text("Pop"),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            const Expanded(
                              flex:3,
                              child: ListTile(
                                title: Text("Title", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),),
                                subtitle: Text("SubTitle"),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Expanded(
                              flex:3,
                              child: Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: scoreKeeper,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: scoreKeeper,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                    child: Row(
                                      children: scoreKeeper,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      )
                  );
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: First, the github uses 7 days vertical and then expands horizontally. You may use wrap, refer to this link. https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-wrap-widget-e1ee0b005b16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your building approach is okey, but you should move your peaces of code to separated widgets
2. You can use GridView

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).